# How to troubleshoot failing connection between cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy and deployed Python Container

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have been working on deploying a simple Django project to Google Cloud Platform.

However the deployed app always fails with, basically this:

```
Django Version: 2.1.3
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:
server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.
Exception Location: /env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py in connect, line 130
Python Executable:  /env/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.6.7
```

I can use exactly the same django project deployment locally - connecting to the same cloud sql instance that the deployed app tries to connect to and it works fine. 
I can duplicate the error locally by simply terminating the local cloud_sql_proxy.

This tells me that the python/django app is working the same both locally and deployed. Also the Cloud SQL Database is working fine, but for some reason either the deployed image gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.05  which I use is not working or somehow my deployed app cannot connect to this proxy.

I have run through deploying the Django Polls app a few times [https://cloud.google.com/python/django/kubernetes-engine]
which is well known to the community and successfully done this a few times to develop some familiarity, then applied
the same steps to my own project as a way of addressing this.

My pod logs are not showing any errors. I have compared my .yaml and Dockerfiles with many examples that work and can find no issues, also other related issues on SO do not seem to address this.

I have tried troubleshooting this for a day or so as a learning process but have made no further progress.

Some help troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The gap in my troubleshooting was that I was not aware that checking the pod logs was not giving me logs from the sql-proxy component, only the app component.
When I checked the logs from the sql proxy it was clear that the Cloud SQL Admin API was not enabled for the project. Enabling it fixed the issue.

Hope this answer helps other googlers.